# google-data-studio grouping most values of dimensions into others category

Tags: looker-studio

I am using Data-Studio to generate charts. I am generating charts for compute instances based on their CPU usage,in time-series. When I generate a chart(a line chart) a few instances are represented as lines in the chart, which have specific CPU usage values, but the majority of instances get accumulated into a category called "**others**" and therefore I am unable to show the metrics for others and the chart is not very useful.

Is there any way this category **others** can be avoided in data studio? so that all the instances are represented by a line or a bar?

I am new to Data-Studio. Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to display the chart **Without** the **Others** series:

### 1) [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart

If you are using **Date** in the X-Axis (**Dimension**) then I'd suggest a Time Series chart as it's designed for Dates, and automatically sorts by Date as well as allowing for Date Range comparison (it also don't display the **Others** series, and series can be displayed as a line or bar).

### 2) [Line](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7398001) Chart

Regarding the initial question (Line Chart) - Tested this out in a number of different Reports and Data Sources to confirm, and it seems to do the trick:

1. Create a **Time Series** chart;
2. Change the **Chart Type** to a Line chart;
3. **Sort** by `Date` in Ascending order.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1e1b27f5-27fd-459f-9f54-6fdd8f4437bb) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]